# Display map in veins

Tags: omnet++, veins

I used veins-4a2. Yesterday, when I launched the simulation as usual my map is not displayed correctly (in the gray area).

What should I do to correct the map display please?  [Here attached the map display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lINkf.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gray area is a module representation by OMNeT++. The [OMNeT++ manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/) has [a whole chapter](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:graphics:display-strings) describing how to modify these settings.
In your simulation you have to modify the `p`parameter to some smaller values that it does not show up so big in your map.

Comment: Thank you for your response Sir.